# Adding Fibonacci odd sequence in java

Tags: java, arrays, fibonacci

I would like to add all the odd numbers in: `System.out.print(store + " ");` 
If you got any suggestion please help me.

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Fibonacci {

    public static void main(String a[]) {

        int Fibcnt = 25;
        int[] feb = new int[Fibcnt];
        feb[0] = 0;
        feb[1] = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i < Fibcnt; i++) {
            feb[i] = feb[i - 1] + feb[i - 2];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < febCount; i++) {
            int store = feb[i];
            if (store % 2 == 1) {
                System.out.print(store + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code didnt work?

Comment: `int sum=0;` outside of loop and `sum += store;` inside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to calculate the sum of all the odd numbers?

Firstly you haven't declared and initialised `febCount` so you need to fix that. In this case `febCount` would be the same as `Fibcnt`, but you could use `feb.length` instead.

```
public class Fibonacci {

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        int Fibcnt = 25;
        int[] feb = new int[Fibcnt];
        feb[0] = 0;
        feb[1] = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i < Fibcnt; i++) {
            feb[i] = feb[i - 1] + feb[i - 2];
        }

        int sum_odd = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < feb.length; i++) {
            if (feb[i] % 2 == 1) {
                sum_odd += feb[i];
                System.out.print(feb[i] + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total of odd numbers: " + sum_odd);
    }
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
1 1 3 5 13 21 55 89 233 377 987 1597 4181 6765 17711 28657 
Total of odd numbers: 60696
```

It looks like you were planning to use `IntStream` to perform the summation, in which case something like this could be used to perform the calculation, however, it would not print the odd values as does your code:

```
int sum_odd = IntStream.of(feb).filter(i -> i%2==1).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your code is you're using an undefined variable name `febCount` in your `for` loop. Should work fine if you change it to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Fibcnt; i++) {
```